# Does ようなところがあった mean "had a tendency to" in this context?

Tags: grammar

> 「私達はエイティシックスで、あの戦場で死ぬはずだったから、ある程度仕方ないんでしょうけど。特にシン君は本当にお兄さんのことだけ、考えていた**ようなところがあった**から。それを無くしてしまって、今は……少し、心配」

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

How should I understand the bold part? I have three interpretations in my mind.

1. there was something he was considering
2. there was a time when he was considering
3. he had a tendency to think about his older brother only

Maybe the bold part is referring to his characteristic? I think it is 3), but I’m not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. It talks about a tendency/characteristic/habit etc.

The pattern is X(に)は...(ような)ところがある = *there is something about X that ...* or *X does ... by habit/nature*. The "..." part can be a clause or an adjective.

- 彼には人を引き付けるところがある He has something that attracts people.
- 彼はやらなければならないことを後回しにするところがある He tends to postpone what he has to do.
- 彼の文章は三島由紀夫を思わせるところがある His prose has something that is reminiscent of Yukio Mishima.